# Extracting text from MS Word Document uploaded through FileUpload from ipyWidgets in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to allow user to upload MS Word file and then I run a certain function that takes a string as input argument. I am uploading Word file through FileUpload however I am getting a coded object. I am unable to decode using byte UTF-8 and using upload.value or upload.data just returns coded text

Any ideas how I can extract content from uploaded Word File?

```
      > upload = widgets.FileUpload() 
        > upload
#I select the file I want to upload
        > upload.value #Returns coded text 
        > upload.data #Returns coded text

        > #Previously upload['content'] worked, but I read this no longer works in IPYWidgets 8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern ms-word files (`.docx`) are actually zip-files.

The text (but not the page headers) are actually inside an XML document called `word/document.xml` in the zip-file.

The `python-docx` module can be used to extract text from these documents. It is mainly used for *creating* documents, but it can read existing ones. Example from [here](https://grokonez.com/python/how-to-read-write-word-docx-files-in-python-docx-module#Get_full-text).

```
>>> import docx
>>> gkzDoc = docx.Document('grokonez.docx')

>>> fullText = []
>>> for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
...     fullText.append(paragraph.text)
...
```

Note that this will only extract the text from paragraphs. Not e.g. the text from tables.

**Edit**:

> I want to be able to upload the MS file through the FileUpload widget.

There are a couple of ways you can do that.

First, isolate the actual file data. `upload.data` is actually a dictionary, see [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#File-Upload). So do something like:

```
rawdata = upload.data[0]
```

(Note that this format has *changed* over different version of ipywidgets. The above example is from the documentation of the latest version.  Read the relevant version of the documentation, or investigate the data in IPython, and adjust accordingly.)

1. write `rawdata` to e.g. `foo.docx` and open that. That would certainly work, but it does seem somewhat un-elegant.
2. `docx.Document` can work with file-like objects. So you could create an `io.BytesIO` object, and use that.

Like this:

```
foo = io.BytesIO(rawdata)
doc = docx.Document(foo)
```

Comment: roland Hello, many thanks for you response. I have used the import docx method u suggested and it works fine. However this works if you are importing your own MS Word file. I want to be able to upload the MS file through the FileUpload widget. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I think your methods are correct however not to upload.data. I've tried both methods and non seem to work. Mainly because upload.data is a zipped list.xml and upload.value is a dictionary. I've tried several methods however all errors come down to the list/dict issue. It is not actually a bytes file. 

Sample output of upload.data :

**[b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\xdf\xa4\xd2lZ\x01\x00\x00 \x05\x00\x00\x13\x00\x08\x02[Content_Types].xml \xa2\x04\x02(\xa0\x00\x02\x00\x00**

Comment: @MarcHenrySaad See updated answer. Apperently the format of `data` has been subject to change.

Comment: Finally worked! Many thanks for your help. I added the final code as a new answer.

FYI, ['content'] is throwing an error as upload.data is the content itself so no need to call content anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking with @Roland Smith great suggestions, following code finally worked:

```
import io
import docx
from docx import Document

    upload = widgets.FileUpload()
    upload

    rawdata = upload.data[0]
    test = io.BytesIO(rawdata)
    doc = Document(test)

    for p in doc.paragraphs:
        print (p.text)
```